# Extract image sources from a web page, where img tags might be added when the page is rendered by javascript etcq

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2012

I want to extract the "" of all the images in a web page in C#/asp.net.

I am using:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string mainSource = client.DownloadString(URL);
```

and searching mainSource string for "".

This method seems to work correctly, but only if all the images(" tags) are present in raw source code of the web page.

The image tags rendered by javascript etc are not being scanned in the above process.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
   HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(/* url */);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"))
 {

 }
```

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'HtmlWeb' could not be found
Error 2 The type or namespace name 'HtmlWeb' could not be found 
Error 3 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'DocumentElement' and no extension method 'DocumentElement' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' could be found

Comment: https://github.com/jstedfast/HtmlAgilityPack/blob/master/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlWeb.Xpath.cs

Comment: You can also find it as a nuget package HtmlAgilityPack